# How to get element beside element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am new to python selenium.

Is it possible to get element that exists always beside another element in selenium?

say i want `.title.may-blank` off https://www.reddit.com/ and is always beside vote count being `div.midcol.unvoted > div.score.unvoted`

[theimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WlRK.png)

I try:

```
//*[contains(@class, "title may-blank ")]/following-sibling::div[@class='midcol unvoted']//*[contains(@class, 'unvoted')]
```

no xpath detected

Comment: Did you try to use the selector in your answer? If so, post your attempt and if it doesn't work the output or error you are getting.

Comment: The css `#thing_t3_7m4st4 > div.midcol.unvoted` doesn't identify any unique `WebElement`. Which `WebElement` are you reffering to exactly?

Comment: @DebanjanB div[@class='midcol unvoted']//*[contains(@class, 'unvoted')] & //*[contains(@class, "title may-blank ")]

Comment: Update the question with the current update for the SO volunteers please.

Comment: So what is your exact Question? Do you want to retrieve **1821** with respect to **.title.may-blank** or just the opposite?

Comment: @DebanjanB Opposite :].  My question is how I can get .title.may-blank with respect to div[@class='midcol unvoted']//*[contains(@class, 'unvoted')]

Comment: I am still not sure why would you try to find a `News Link` with respect to `Upvotes Count`. Rather you should be doing the reverse.

Comment: @DebanjanB I think either option works :).  I am just practising on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the first **`Upvote Count`** through the fowwowing `CSS` or `XPATH` :

- **`CSS`** :

  ```
  div#thing_t3_7m64jy > div.midcol.unvoted > div.score.unvoted
  ```
- **`XPATH`** :

  ```
  //div[@id='thing_t3_7m64jy']//div[@class='midcol unvoted']//div[@class='score unvoted']
  ```

Identify the first **`News Item`** with respect to the **`Upvote Count`** through the following `XPATH` :

- **`XPATH`** :

  ```
  //div[@id='thing_t3_7m64jy']//div[@class='midcol unvoted']//div[@class='score unvoted']//following::a[2]
  ```